# Unable to save changes to files in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution that is under source control (TFS, Visual Studio Online). It is mapped to a local workspace, I have checked out some files (e.g. web.config, global.asax).

When I try to save any changes to files I get a 'Save File As' dialog, and if I hit Save it warns me the file already exists (say, web.config), and asks me if I want to replace it. If I hit Yes I get I get an error dialog saying 'the process cannot access the file '....\wyfvmjia.p1p~' because it is used by another process. I have no idea what this file is or how it is related to the file (web.config) I am trying to save.

This is infuriating, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1:

It looks like the Visual Studio process (devenv.exe) is creating and deleting random temporary files in the same folder (e.g. wyfvmjia.p1p~) and is causing a 'sharing violation' on those files (I used a sys internals utility to monitor the folder) when I am trying to save let's say web.config.

EDIT 2:

[This](https://github.com/codereflection/Giles/issues/40) seems to suggest in one of the comments that VS2013 creates a copy of a file and then replaces the original when trying to save a file in your project. This would explain why I see temporary files getting created and deleted. It's odd I get the 'Save File As' dialog though. It looks like some other process (antivirus?) gets hold of the temporary file before VS can do something with it?

EDIT 3:

I created a console application project with only a program.cs file and the same is happening. This may be a problem with Antivirus software interfering with the VS2013 'copy-replace' feature.

EDIT 4:

Changed title. Still have not been able to find a solution.

EDIT 5:

See the accepted answer. Apologies for not getting back earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by disk encryption software. Disabling the disk encryption software services each time after starting VS2013 solves the problem. I did not have this problem with earlier versions of Visual Studio, presumably because of the new copy-replace cycle adopted by VS2013 mentioned in EDIT 2 in my original question.

Apologies for not coming back to comment and answer my original question, I completely forgot about it.

Comment: hi. :) how can I disable the disk encryption software? Can you give me some steps? Thanks

Comment: I love how people just stop back to say "I fixed it!" and don't say how.  Like... ok, great for you, but you're just gloating.

Answer (score 8):

For me it was Google Drive.
Once I've closed it, I was able to save the file.

Comment: Good catch! Was driving me insane, your suggestion sorted the issue immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: Once I thought that would be a good solution myself. In a result Visual Studio made all project files required with administrator permission. Had to clone whole project all over. Be advised.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions might be the problem. Or you could be opening some readonly files.
It's worth to mention that some of the extensions can turn any file you create in to a readonly file, and this would be the same result that you're facing.

So first, disable all extensions, and check for the little icon near the files's name (in the tab) that indicates a readonly file.

Comment: Thanks @mr992, upvoted. See EDIT 1 above, I don't think either file permissions or extensions are causing this but I may be wrong! Is there an easy way to view and disable extensions for a solution?

Comment: @martijn_himself to be on the safe side, if you haven't already, go to Tools->Extensions and Updates... And disable all extensions. It's very common that VS creates and deletes temp files on the go. Are you experiencing this in all the solutions or only in this one?

Comment: @martijn_himself did you check if there's the 'readonly' icon? It's like a small lock icon in the tab just after the file's name.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. See EDIT 2. The file is checked out (there is no lock icon). I have also copied the solution and removed the bindings to source control but the problem remains. I am going to have a look to see what happens if I create new project from scratch (I have just installed VS2013 and this was the first project).

Comment: @martijn_himself alright, if you haven't already add an exception to a folder in your antivirus, make a new project and try again. Make sure you add a global exception (for all the features). This depends on the antivirus you have. Also, don't enable the version control system you're using (tfs) just to be sure.

Comment: @martijn_himself does this apply for ALL the files in your project? Did you add a new file and the same happened?

Comment: Have this same problem, but seems to be project specific. Creating and editing a new project does not have the problem when saving.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was caused by "Backup and Sync from Google". After I’ve closed it everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. It went away once I uninstalled VS 2013 and installed VS 2012 instead. Good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem on a company computer.  I had to uninstall VS 2013 RC2 and reinstall vs2013 ultimate.  Then I had to go through the update process for update 1. I believe it must by the Symantec progressive scan along with the VS 2013 upgrade handling of files.  I guess the moral of the story, if I can be so cliché is "If it aint broke don't fix it".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and created a bug on Connect.  Let's hope this gets fixed

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/860265/unable-to-save-files-in-vs-2013-update-2-rc2

Answer (score 1):

I got mine fixed by making a copy of all the files with git clone then deleting all old files and pasting the copied versions over it. Not sure how this fixed permissions or an antivirus denying permission but it did

Answer (score 0):

martijn_himself sounds correct, problem could be because of Disk Encryption Software. This problem started om my PC when i changed settings (domain etc) on Disk Encryption Software. and a simple "Update 2" for VS2013 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with only one html file in a project. For me it seems to have something to do with VPN that I was using to upload this html file to CRM system. Whenever it was on it seemed to "block" the file somehow. When I closed the window where I was uploading the html file I can save without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions here but none worked. Then, with the modified file open in Visual Studio, I navigated to the file on disk and deleted it. Then clicked build and the save file dialog no longer popped up. I was able to build and check in.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was Windows' **Controlled Folder Access**, even though I didn't get the standard warning/error. In "Allow an app through...", I had to add

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

(Backup and Sync from Google) when I close it The problem vanished