# Every action I take, Visual Studio opens up the 'save file as' dialog

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I try to debug and/or run in VS2015, a 'save file as' dialogue opens up. not knowing what to do my first thought is to exit and reopen, but when I try to save the project first, again the dialogue appears! when I try to cooperate and save it under that file name a message appears saying this file already exists and when I try to replace it an error dialogue appears saying the file is being used by another process.

I have tried:

1. open VS prompt --> devenv /ResetSettings
2. run as administrator
3. clearing ReSharper cache

Nothing worked.
Help would be very much appreciated

Update: after clearing ReSharper cache it seemed like the issue was solved, but it wasn't. I can't point out when exactly it happens. it feels like this happens randomly.

Comment: Your project files may be marked as read-only.

Comment: @John Strit which files exactly?  The .sln and .c files were already unchecked. I now tried to uncheck the 'Read-only' under the project's properties (in Windows Explorer), but when i apply, close and re-open properties, the checkbox is again marked. still didn't solve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883085/unable-to-save-changes-to-files-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: run visual as administrator may works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by closing Google drive.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the file that I was being asked to save it and resaved it (created it) or something and it worked. The file was `Form1.cs`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).